# Could not remove sensitive data

Tags: git

I have a problem with removing sensitive data from one of my git reps.
I read the man page at https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data and followed the instructions one by one.

at first I did this with success:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/defunkt/github-gem.git
```

next I did this with succes

```
$ cd github-gem
```

and then I tried the following with no success and got the following message

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

fatal: ambigous argument 'rm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to seperate paths from revisions
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while, but for posterity's sake:
I fought with this issue for a while now - the solution on Windows is to use " (double quote) instead of ' (single quote).

Answer (score 1):

I think even with `--ignore-unmatch` you still need the `--` disambiguator. Like:

```
git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -- Rakefile
                                 ^^-this two dashes here
```

Comment: thx for reply. i tried it but get the same error message :-( maybe its helpful to know that i am working with windows 7.